# What is the sum of this series? $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(1-n)(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I want to know what is the sum of this series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(1-n)(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{n-1}}$$

$B_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers. Mathematica does not help.

Comment: Now I fixed the problem. Sorry. In this form it is exactly what I want.

Comment: You mentionned bernouilli numbers. Is it involved in the sum? Note that for $n=2k+1$, $\zeta{(1-n)}=0$

Comment: The sum diverges

Comment: You can calculate it exactly using the answer given by @Marco Cantarini using Borel resummation.  So, divide the summand by (2n)! and multiply by $\int_0^{\infty}x^{2n}\exp(-x)dx$ and interchange integration and summation (which is illegal but this illegal act will correct the illegal act that led to the divergent summation in the first place). The summation can then be calculated exactly, but you then end up with a double integral (one due to the Borel resummation procedure another one to deal with the extra factor of n in the denominator). You have to see if you can simplify the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get using Noerlund-Summation for divergent series, with 128 terms of the series (63 nonzero):

```
  -0.4592743090 | 805...       \\ by Noerlund-Summation 64 nonzero terms
  -0.4592743090 | 7704...      \\ = 2*(log(2) +Eulergamma - (1+1/2))
```

If we use $x=3$ instead of $x=2$ in the denominator of your series we get with the same Noerlund-summation

```
 -0.4725161392 | 7932...       \\ by Noerlund-Summation 64 nonzero terms
 -0.4725161392 | 9107...       \\ =  3*(log(3) +Euler  -(1+1/2+1/3))
```

This reminds me of the psi-function; I think that was

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} { \zeta(1-k) \over x^{k}} = (\log(x) + \gamma  -(1+\frac 12+ \frac 13+...+ \frac 1x)) $$

see $\psi (x)$ around $x=\infty$ at [wolfram-alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=digamma%28x%29+around+x%3Dinfinity)  or see eq (16) at Eric Weissstein's [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html)

[update] To see some more interesting generalization we can combine the zetas with binomial-coefficients, and build a matrix $Z$ of this *(which is also the matrix of the Faulhaber-polynomials for the summing of like powers, exended by one column, but transposed)* then I get the following partial sums (row-for-row) for the Noerlund-sums with $x=2$ and 128 rows:

```
    ...                ...             ...                ...
  -0.229637154554  0.394934066767  0.0770569035573   0.0198232345545   
  -0.229637154551  0.394934066766  0.0770569034932   0.0198232345458   ...
  -0.229637154549  0.394934066767  0.0770569034357   0.0198232345259   (128 terms)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ~    gamma       ~  zeta(2)      ~    zeta(3)      ~    zeta(4)
    -(1+1/2)       -(1+1/2^2)        -(1+1/2^3)        -(1+1/2^4)
    -log(1/2)
```

*(The first column gives the result of your question for $x=2$).*

To have an idea how the [Z-matrix looks like (pg 23 ff)](http://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/04_3_SummingOfLikePowers.pdf) here is the top-left segment, beginning with $\zeta(0)$ at the entries of the diagonal, and I do the dot-product with a row-vector of powers of $ \frac 1x$ from the left:

$$\small \begin{bmatrix} \begin{array} {r}
 -1/2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -1/12 & -1/2 & -1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & -1/6 & -1/2 & -1/3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 1/120 & 0 & -1/4 & -1/2 & -1/4 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 1/30 & 0 & -1/3 & -1/2 & -1/5 \\ 
 -1/252 & 0 & 1/12 & 0 & -5/12 & -1/2 \end{array}
 \end{bmatrix}$$

---

*(Remark: I had the alternating sign missing in my first version of the answer)*

Answer (score 3):

This question is very similar to your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413525/what-is-the-sum-of-this-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n-1n1-b-nn). We have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\zeta\left(1-n\right)\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{2^{n-1}}=\zeta\left(0\right)+\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\zeta\left(1-n\right)\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{2^{n-1}}
 $$ and using the identity $$B_{n}=-n\zeta\left(1-n\right)
 $$ for $n\geq2
 $, we have $$=\zeta\left(0\right)-\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{B_{n}\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n2^{n-1}}=\zeta\left(0\right)-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{B_{2n}\left(-1\right)^{2n+1}}{n2^{2n}}
 $$ because $B_{2n+1}=0\ \forall n\geq1
 $ and using the asymptotics $$\left(-1\right)^{n+1}B_{2n}\sim4\sqrt{\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{\pi e}\right)^{2n}
 $$ we have $$\sim\zeta\left(0\right)-4\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{n}{2\pi e}\right)^{2n}
 $$ and so the series diverges.